# Calling Scala's method from Java with Scala's collection type

Tags: java, scala

I have a Java code calling Scala method.

Java side code:

```
List<String> contexts = Arrays.asList(initialContext);
ContextMessage c = ContextMessage.load(contexts);
```

Scala side code:

```
def load(contexts: List[String]) = ...
    contexts foreach context =>
```

[image]

In this case, I have `scala.collection.immutable.List<String> cannot be applied ...` error message.

I also need to make the type of contexts as general as possible (i.e., Seq) as the load method iterates over the given collection object to process something.

```
def load(contexts: Seq[String]) = ...
```

How to solve the two issues?

Comment: What's wrong with just using `JavaConversions` ? This is the standard way to communicate between Java and Scala for collections

Comment: [JavaConversions](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.JavaConversions$): specifically, `asScalaBuffer`.

Comment: BTW using a Java type in a Scala code is wrong to my opinion, especially `List` because it has a particular meaning and is associated to specific constructs in Scala

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just use `JavaConversions` and keep my Scala code *scalatic*.

```
 // Scala code
object ContextMessage {
    def load(contexts: Seq[String]) = ???
}

// in your Java code
ContextMessage c = ContextMessage.load(JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(Arrays.asList(initialContext));
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case Scala calling this method, Implicit conversion between java.util.ArrayList and Seq type can solve this issue easily.

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

object ContextMessage  extends App  {

    implicit def typeConversion(input: java.util.ArrayList[String]) = {
        val res : ListBuffer[String] = new ListBuffer[String]()
        for (i <- 0 to input.size - 1) {
            // println(input.get(i))
            res += input.get(i)
        }
        res
    }

    def load(contexts: Seq[String]) = {
        contexts foreach { c =>
            println(c)
        }
    }

    val x = new java.util.ArrayList[String]()
    x.add("A")
    x.add("B")
    load(x)
}

ContextMessage.main(args)
```

The result shows:

```
A
B
```

Comment: Every time you call your method you create a new list, it's not great. I have not actually checked what the Scala conversions do, but I guess they just define wrappers around Java objects (I will have a look into that)

Comment: Yeah, that's the case, these are just wrappes, it's much more efficient : https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/library/scala/collection/convert/WrapAsScala.scala