# I know how to do an orderBy("a", "b"...), a groupBy on a dataset. I need to perform calculations and work on each subset of records, idependently

Tags: java, apache-spark

I'm reading an accounting file for cities. My goal is to offer some informative subtotals for each accounting number of each establishment :

Some columns, named from (*cumulSD3*, *cumulSC3*) to (*cumulSD7*, *cumulSC7*) are added to the records, and aggregates *soldeDebiteur* and *soldeCrediteur* for root accounts : account number `13248` will aggregate under `13248`, `1324` and `132` levels, in example.

```
+--------------------------+----------+-----------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------+----------+------------+-----------+------------+----------+---------------------+-----------+------------+------------------+-------------------+------------------------+-------------------------+---------------------------+----------------------------+-----------------------------+------------------------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+---------------+--------------------------+--------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+------------+----------------+----------------+----------+----------+----------------+----------+----------+----------------+----------+---------+---------------+-----------+--------------+----------------+--------+---------+
|libelleBudget             |typeBudget|typeEtablissement|sousTypeEtablissement|nomenclatureComptable|siren    |codeRegion|codeActivite|codeSecteur|numeroFINESS|codeBudget|categorieCollectivite|typeBalance|numeroCompte|balanceEntreeDebit|balanceEntreeCredit|operationBudgetaireDebit|operationBudgetaireCredit|operationNonBudgetaireDebit|operationNonBudgetaireCredit|operationOrdreBudgetaireDebit|operationOrdreBudgetaireCredit|soldeDebiteur|soldeCrediteur|anneeExercice|budgetPrincipal|nombreChiffresNumeroCompte|cumulSD7|cumulSC7|libelleCompte                                                                                        |nomenclatureComptablePlan|sirenCommune|populationTotale|numeroCompteSur3|cumulSD3  |cumulSC3  |numeroCompteSur4|cumulSD4  |cumulSC4  |numeroCompteSur5|cumulSD5  |cumulSC5 |codeDepartement|codeCommune|siret         |numeroCompteSur6|cumulSD6|cumulSC6 |
+--------------------------+----------+-----------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------+----------+------------+-----------+------------+----------+---------------------+-----------+------------+------------------+-------------------+------------------------+-------------------------+---------------------------+----------------------------+-----------------------------+------------------------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+---------------+--------------------------+--------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+------------+----------------+----------------+----------+----------+----------------+----------+----------+----------------+----------+---------+---------------+-----------+--------------+----------------+--------+---------+
|ABERGEMENT-CLEMENCIAT (L')|1         |101              |00                   |M14                  |210100012|084       |40          |null       |null        |null      |Commune              |DEF        |1021        |0.0               |349139.71          |0.0                     |0.0                      |0.0                        |0.0                         |0.0                          |0.0                           |0.0          |349139.71     |2019         |true           |4                         |0.0     |0.0     |Dotation                                                                                             |M14                      |210100012   |794             |102             |0.0       |995427.19 |1021            |0.0       |349139.71 |1021            |0.0       |0.0      |01             |01001      |21010001200017|1021            |0.0     |0.0      |
|ABERGEMENT-CLEMENCIAT (L')|1         |101              |00                   |M14                  |210100012|084       |40          |null       |null        |null      |Commune              |DEF        |10222       |0.0               |554545.85          |0.0                     |30003.0                  |0.0                        |0.0                         |0.0                          |0.0                           |0.0          |584548.85     |2019         |true           |5                         |0.0     |0.0     |F.C.T.V.A.                                                                                           |M14                      |210100012   |794             |102             |0.0       |995427.19 |1022            |0.0       |646287.48 |10222           |0.0       |584548.85|01             |01001      |21010001200017|10222           |0.0     |0.0      |
|ABERGEMENT-CLEMENCIAT (L')|1         |101              |00                   |M14                  |210100012|084       |40          |null       |null        |null      |Commune              |DEF        |10223       |0.0               |4946.0             |0.0                     |0.0                      |0.0                        |0.0                         |0.0                          |0.0                           |0.0          |4946.0        |2019         |true           |5                         |0.0     |0.0     |T.L.E.                                                                                               |M14                      |210100012   |794             |102             |0.0       |995427.19 |1022            |0.0       |646287.48 |10223           |0.0       |4946.0   |01             |01001      |21010001200017|10223           |0.0     |0.0      |
|ABERGEMENT-CLEMENCIAT (L')|1         |101              |00                   |M14                  |210100012|084       |40          |null       |null        |null      |Commune              |DEF        |10226       |0.0               |41753.65           |0.0                     |12078.54                 |0.0                        |0.0                         |0.0                          |0.0                           |0.0          |53832.19      |2019         |true           |5                         |0.0     |0.0     |Taxe d’aménagement                                                                                   |M14                      |210100012   |794             |102             |0.0       |995427.19 |1022            |0.0       |646287.48 |10226           |0.0       |53832.19 |01             |01001      |21010001200017|10226           |0.0     |0.0      |
|ABERGEMENT-CLEMENCIAT (L')|1         |101              |00                   |M14                  |210100012|084       |40          |null       |null        |null      |Commune              |DEF        |10227       |0.0               |2960.44            |0.0                     |0.0                      |0.0                        |0.0                         |0.0                          |0.0                           |0.0          |2960.44       |2019         |true           |5                         |0.0     |0.0     |Versement pour sous-densité                                                                          |M14                      |210100012   |794             |102             |0.0       |995427.19 |1022            |0.0       |646287.48 |10227           |0.0       |2960.44  |01             |01001      |21010001200017|10227           |0.0     |0.0      |
|ABERGEMENT-CLEMENCIAT (L')|1         |101              |00                   |M14                  |210100012|084       |40          |null       |null        |null      |Commune              |DEF        |1068        |0.0               |2281475.34         |0.0                     |0.0                      |0.0                        |0.0                         |0.0                          |0.0                           |0.0          |2281475.34    |2019         |true           |4                         |0.0     |0.0     |Excédents de fonctionnement capitalisés                                                              |M14                      |210100012   |794             |106             |0.0       |2281475.34|1068            |0.0       |2281475.34|1068            |0.0       |0.0      |01             |01001      |21010001200017|1068            |0.0     |0.0      |
|ABERGEMENT-CLEMENCIAT (L')|1         |101              |00                   |M14                  |210100012|084       |40          |null       |null        |null      |Commune              |DEF        |110         |0.0               |97772.73           |0.0                     |0.0                      |0.0                        |112620.66                   |0.0                          |0.0                           |0.0          |210393.39     |2019         |true           |3                         |0.0     |0.0     |Report à nouveau (solde créditeur)                                                                   |M14                      |210100012   |794             |110             |0.0       |210393.39 |110             |0.0       |0.0       |110             |0.0       |0.0      |01             |01001      |21010001200017|110             |0.0     |0.0      |
|ABERGEMENT-CLEMENCIAT (L')|1         |101              |00                   |M14                  |210100012|084       |40          |null       |null        |null      |Commune              |DEF        |12          |0.0               |112620.66          |0.0                     |0.0                      |112620.66                  |0.0                         |0.0                          |0.0                           |0.0          |0.0           |2019         |true           |2                         |0.0     |0.0     |RÉSULTAT DE L'EXERCICE (excédentaire ou déficitaire)                                                 |M14                      |210100012   |794             |12              |0.0       |0.0       |12              |0.0       |0.0       |12              |0.0       |0.0      |01             |01001      |21010001200017|12              |0.0     |0.0      |
|ABERGEMENT-CLEMENCIAT (L')|1         |101              |00                   |M14                  |210100012|084       |40          |null       |null        |null      |Commune              |DEF        |1321        |0.0               |29097.78           |0.0                     |0.0                      |0.0                        |0.0                         |0.0                          |0.0                           |0.0          |29097.78      |2019         |true           |4                         |0.0     |0.0     |État et établissements nationaux                                                                     |M14                      |210100012   |794             |132             |0.0       |296722.26 |1321            |0.0       |29097.78  |1321            |0.0       |0.0      |01             |01001      |21010001200017|1321            |0.0     |0.0      |
|ABERGEMENT-CLEMENCIAT (L')|1         |101              |00                   |M14                  |210100012|084       |40          |null       |null        |null      |Commune              |DEF        |1322        |0.0               |201.67             |0.0                     |0.0                      |0.0                        |0.0                         |0.0                          |0.0                           |0.0          |201.67        |2019         |true           |4                         |0.0     |0.0     |Régions                                                                                              |M14                      |210100012   |794             |132             |0.0       |296722.26 |1322            |0.0       |201.67    |1322            |0.0       |0.0      |01             |01001      |21010001200017|1322            |0.0     |0.0      |
|ABERGEMENT-CLEMENCIAT (L')|1         |101              |00                   |M14                  |210100012|084       |40          |null       |null        |null      |Commune              |DEF        |1323        |0.0               |163194.37          |0.0                     |0.0                      |0.0                        |0.0                         |0.0                          |0.0                           |0.0          |163194.37     |2019         |true           |4                         |0.0     |0.0     |Départements                                                                                         |M14                      |210100012   |794             |132             |0.0       |296722.26 |1323            |0.0       |163194.37 |1323            |0.0       |0.0      |01             |01001      |21010001200017|1323            |0.0     |0.0      |
|ABERGEMENT-CLEMENCIAT (L')|1         |101              |00                   |M14                  |210100012|084       |40          |null       |null        |null      |Commune              |DEF        |13248       |0.0               |1129.37            |0.0                     |0.0                      |0.0                        |0.0                         |0.0                          |0.0                           |0.0          |1129.37       |2019         |true           |5                         |0.0     |0.0     |Autres communes                                                                                      |M14                      |210100012   |794             |132             |0.0       |296722.26 |1324            |0.0       |1129.37   |13248           |0.0       |1129.37  |01             |01001      |21010001200017|13248           |0.0     |0.0      |
|ABERGEMENT-CLEMENCIAT (L')|1         |101              |00                   |M14                  |210100012|084       |40          |null       |null        |null      |Commune              |DEF        |13251       |0.0               |47079.11           |0.0                     |2387.05                  |0.0                        |0.0                         |0.0                          |0.0                           |0.0          |49466.16      |2019         |true           |5                         |0.0     |0.0     |GFP de rattachement                                                                                  |M14                      |210100012   |794             |132             |0.0       |296722.26 |1325            |0.0       |49532.16  |13251           |0.0       |49466.16 |01             |01001      |21010001200017|13251           |0.0     |0.0      |
|ABERGEMENT-CLEMENCIAT (L')|1         |101              |00                   |M14                  |210100012|084       |40          |null       |null        |null      |Commune              |DEF        |13258       |0.0               |66.0               |0.0                     |0.0                      |0.0                        |0.0                         |0.0                          |0.0                           |0.0          |66.0          |2019         |true           |5                         |0.0     |0.0     |Autres groupements                                                                                   |M14                      |210100012   |794             |132             |0.0       |296722.26 |1325            |0.0       |49532.16  |13258           |0.0       |66.0     |01             |01001      |21010001200017|13258           |0.0     |0.0      |
```

To be clearer, retaining only the main fields involved in calculations, here's what my function focus on :

```
+--------------+------------+-------------+--------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+---------+---------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|         siret|numeroCompte|soldeDebiteur|soldeCrediteur|cumulSD7|cumulSC7|cumulSD6|cumulSC6| cumulSD5| cumulSC5|  cumulSD4|  cumulSC4|  cumulSD3|  cumulSC3|
+--------------+------------+-------------+--------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+---------+---------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|21010001200017|        1021|          0.0|     349139.71|     0.0|     0.0|     0.0|     0.0|      0.0|      0.0|       0.0| 349139.71|       0.0| 995427.19|
|21010001200017|       10222|          0.0|     584548.85|     0.0|     0.0|     0.0|     0.0|      0.0|584548.85|       0.0| 646287.48|       0.0| 995427.19|
|21010001200017|       10223|          0.0|        4946.0|     0.0|     0.0|     0.0|     0.0|      0.0|   4946.0|       0.0| 646287.48|       0.0| 995427.19|
|21010001200017|       10226|          0.0|      53832.19|     0.0|     0.0|     0.0|     0.0|      0.0| 53832.19|       0.0| 646287.48|       0.0| 995427.19|
|21010001200017|       10227|          0.0|       2960.44|     0.0|     0.0|     0.0|     0.0|      0.0|  2960.44|       0.0| 646287.48|       0.0| 995427.19|
|21010001200017|        1068|          0.0|    2281475.34|     0.0|     0.0|     0.0|     0.0|      0.0|      0.0|       0.0|2281475.34|       0.0|2281475.34|
|21010001200017|         110|          0.0|     210393.39|     0.0|     0.0|     0.0|     0.0|      0.0|      0.0|       0.0|       0.0|       0.0| 210393.39|
|21010001200017|          12|          0.0|           0.0|     0.0|     0.0|     0.0|     0.0|      0.0|      0.0|       0.0|       0.0|       0.0|       0.0|
|21010001200017|        1321|          0.0|      29097.78|     0.0|     0.0|     0.0|     0.0|      0.0|      0.0|       0.0|  29097.78|       0.0| 296722.26|
|21010001200017|        1322|          0.0|        201.67|     0.0|     0.0|     0.0|     0.0|      0.0|      0.0|       0.0|    201.67|       0.0| 296722.26|
|21010001200017|        1323|          0.0|     163194.37|     0.0|     0.0|     0.0|     0.0|      0.0|      0.0|       0.0| 163194.37|       0.0| 296722.26|
|21010001200017|       13248|          0.0|       1129.37|     0.0|     0.0|     0.0|     0.0|      0.0|  1129.37|       0.0|   1129.37|       0.0| 296722.26|
|21010001200017|       13251|          0.0|      49466.16|     0.0|     0.0|     0.0|     0.0|      0.0| 49466.16|       0.0|  49532.16|       0.0| 296722.26|
|21010001200017|       13258|          0.0|          66.0|     0.0|     0.0|     0.0|     0.0|      0.0|     66.0|       0.0|  49532.16|       0.0| 296722.26|
|21010001200017|        1328|          0.0|      53566.91|     0.0|     0.0|     0.0|     0.0|      0.0|      0.0|       0.0|  53566.91|       0.0| 296722.26|
|21010001200017|        1341|          0.0|     142734.21|     0.0|     0.0|     0.0|     0.0|      0.0|      0.0|       0.0| 142734.21|       0.0| 145233.21|
|21010001200017|        1342|          0.0|        2499.0|     0.0|     0.0|     0.0|     0.0|      0.0|      0.0|       0.0|    2499.0|       0.0| 145233.21|
|21010001200017|        1383|          0.0|       2550.01|     0.0|     0.0|     0.0|     0.0|      0.0|      0.0|       0.0|   2550.01|       0.0|   2550.01|
|21010001200017|        1641|          0.0|     236052.94|     0.0|     0.0|     0.0|     0.0|      0.0|      0.0|       0.0| 236052.94|       0.0| 236052.94|
```

This starts on an accounting file sorted by *department*, *city code*, *account number*, *siret* (our identifier for establishments).
However, lacking of knowledge, I'm doing something that breaks the heart :

### First attempt that is costly but works, through RDD

```java
/**
 * Créer un dataset de cumuls de comptes parents par siret.
 * @param session Session Spark.
 * @param comptes Dataset des comptes de comptabilités de tous les siret.
 * @return Dataset avec un siret associés à des cumuls par comptes à 7, 6, 5, 4, 3 chiffres, pour soldes de débit et soldes de crédit.
 */
private Dataset<Row> cumulsComptesParentsParSiret(SparkSession session, Dataset<Row> comptes) {
   JavaPairRDD<String, Iterable<Row>> rddComptesParSiret = comptes.javaRDD().groupBy((Function<Row, String>)compte -> compte.getAs("siret"));
   
   // Réaliser les cumuls par siret et compte, par compte parent.
   JavaRDD<Row> rdd = rddComptesParSiret.flatMap((FlatMapFunction<Tuple2<String, Iterable<Row>>, Row>)comptesSiret -> {
      String siret = comptesSiret._1();
      AccumulateurCompte comptesParentsPourSiret = new AccumulateurCompte(siret);

      for(Row rowCompte : comptesSiret._2()) {
         String numeroCompte = rowCompte.getAs("numeroCompte");
         Double soldeSD = rowCompte.getAs("soldeDebiteur");
         Double soldeSC = rowCompte.getAs("soldeCrediteur");
         
         comptesParentsPourSiret.add(numeroCompte, soldeSD, soldeSC);
      }

      // Faire une ligne de regroupement siret, compte et ses comptes parents.
      List<Row> rowsCumulsPourSiret = new ArrayList<>();
      
      for(Row rowCompte : comptesSiret._2()) {
         String numeroCompte = rowCompte.getAs("numeroCompte");
         double sd[] = new double[6]; 
         double sc[] = new double[6]; 
         
         for(int nombreChiffres = numeroCompte.length(); nombreChiffres >= 3; nombreChiffres--) {
            String compteParent = numeroCompte.substring(0, nombreChiffres);
            Double cumulDebits = comptesParentsPourSiret.getCumulSD(compteParent);
            Double cumulCredits = comptesParentsPourSiret.getCumulSC(compteParent);
            
            sd[nombreChiffres - 3] = cumulDebits != null ? Precision.round(cumulDebits, 2, BigDecimal.ROUND_CEILING) : 0.0;
            sc[nombreChiffres - 3] = cumulCredits != null ? Precision.round(cumulCredits, 2, BigDecimal.ROUND_CEILING) : 0.0;
         }
         
         Row rowCumulsPourCompte = RowFactory.create(siret, numeroCompte, sd[4], sc[4], sd[3], sc[3], sd[2], sc[2], sd[1], sc[1], sd[0], sc[0]);
         rowsCumulsPourSiret.add(rowCumulsPourCompte);
      }
      
      return rowsCumulsPourSiret.iterator();
   });
   
   return session.createDataFrame(rdd, schemaCumulComptesParents());
}
```

---

### Second attempt, through datasets : efficient, but doesn't allow low-level management of accounting records

```java
/**
 * Cumuler les sous-comptes.
 * @param comptes Dataset de comptes.
 * @return Dataset aux cumuls de comptes à 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 chiffres réalisés, par commune.
 */
private Dataset<Row> cumulsSousComptes(Dataset<Row> comptes) {
   Dataset<Row> comptesAvecCumuls = comptes; 
   
   for(int nombreChiffresNiveauCompte = 3; nombreChiffresNiveauCompte < 7; nombreChiffresNiveauCompte ++) {
      comptesAvecCumuls = cumulsCompteParent(comptesAvecCumuls, nombreChiffresNiveauCompte);
   }
   
   return comptesAvecCumuls;
}

/**
 * Cumul par un niveau de compte parent.
 * @param comptes Liste des comptes.
 * @param nombreChiffres Nombre de chiffres auquel réduire le compte à cummuler. Exemple 4 : 2041582 est cumulé sur 2041. 
 * @return cumuls par compte parent : dataset au format (cumul des soldes débiteurs, cumul des soldes créditeurs).
 */
private Dataset<Row> cumulsCompteParent(Dataset<Row> comptes, int nombreChiffres) {
   // Cumuler pour un niveau de compte parent sur le préfixe de leurs comptes réduits à nombreChiffres.
   Column nombreChiffresCompte = comptes.col("nombreChiffresNumeroCompte");
   
   String aliasNumeroCompte = MessageFormat.format("numeroCompteSur{0}", nombreChiffres);
   RelationalGroupedDataset group = comptes.groupBy(col("codeDepartement"), col("codeCommune"), col("siret"), col("numeroCompte").substr(1,nombreChiffres).as(aliasNumeroCompte));
   
   String nomChampCumulSD = MessageFormat.format("cumulSD{0}", nombreChiffres);
   String nomChampCumulSC = MessageFormat.format("cumulSC{0}", nombreChiffres);
   Column sd = sum(when(nombreChiffresCompte.$greater$eq(lit(nombreChiffres)), col("soldeDebiteur")).otherwise(lit(0.0))).as(nomChampCumulSD);
   Column sc = sum(when(nombreChiffresCompte.$greater$eq(lit(nombreChiffres)), col("soldeCrediteur")).otherwise(lit(0.0))).as(nomChampCumulSC);

   Dataset<Row> cumuls = group.agg(sd, sc);
   
   // Associer à chaque compte la colonne de cumuls de comptes parents, pour le niveau en question.
   Column jointure =  
      comptes.col("codeDepartement").equalTo(cumuls.col("codeDepartement"))
      .and(comptes.col("codeCommune").equalTo(cumuls.col("codeCommune")))
      .and(comptes.col("siret").equalTo(cumuls.col("siret")))
      .and(comptes.col("numeroCompte").substr(1, nombreChiffres).equalTo(cumuls.col(aliasNumeroCompte)));

   Dataset<Row> comptesAvecCumuls = comptes.join(cumuls, jointure, "left_outer")
      .drop(comptes.col("siret"))
      .drop(comptes.col("codeDepartement"))
      .drop(comptes.col("codeCommune"))
      .drop(comptes.col(nomChampCumulSD))
      .drop(comptes.col(nomChampCumulSC))
      .withColumnRenamed("cumulSD", nomChampCumulSD)
      .withColumnRenamed("cumulSC", nomChampCumulSC)
      .withColumn(nomChampCumulSD, round(col(nomChampCumulSD), 2))
      .withColumn(nomChampCumulSC, round(col(nomChampCumulSC), 2));
   
   return comptesAvecCumuls;
}
```

By low level management, I mean : some last minute verifications to emit some warnings or exclude at summation time some values :

- If accounting nomenclature changes for one record among those of establishment.
- To warn about a value that seems strange, regarding to other knowledge I have.

---

### What I would like to have

I need to browse the rows content of each group independently. One group after the other.

I would need a *Spark* function that would offer me to implement a call-back method, where :

- the first parameter would give the current keys values (for *department code*, *city code*, *siret*),
- and the second one, the rows associated with these keys.

```java
Dataset<Row> eachGroupContent(Row keys, Dataset<Row> groupContent);
```

It would be successively called by *Spark* with these entries parameters :

```
Row (keys) : {Department : 01, City code : 01001, siret : 21010001200017}

Dataset<Row> (values) associated :
+---------------+-----------+--------------+------------+-------------+--------------+--------+
|codeDepartement|codeCommune|         siret|numeroCompte|soldeDebiteur|soldeCrediteur|(others)|
+---------------+-----------+--------------+------------+-------------+--------------+--------+
|             01|      01001|21010001200017|        1021|          0.0|     349139.71|     ...|
|             01|      01001|21010001200017|       10222|          0.0|     584548.85|     ...|
|             01|      01001|21010001200017|       10223|          0.0|        4946.0|     ...|
|             01|      01001|21010001200017|       10226|          0.0|      53832.19|     ...|
```

```
Row : {Department : 01, City code : 01001, siret : 21010001200033}

Dataset<Row> :
|             01|      01001|21010001200033|        1021|          0.0|      38863.22|     ...|
|             01|      01001|21010001200033|       10222|          0.0|       62067.0|     ...|
|             01|      01001|21010001200033|       10228|          0.0|        9666.0|     ...|
|             01|      01001|21010001200033|        1068|          0.0|     100121.62|     ...|
```

```
Row : {Department : 01, City code : 01001, siret : 21010001200066}

Dataset<Row> :
|             01|      01001|21010001200066|        1641|          0.0|      100000.0|     ...|
|             01|      01001|21010001200066|        3355|    587689.33|           0.0|     ...|
|             01|      01001|21010001200066|        4011|          0.0|           0.0|     ...|
|             01|      01001|21010001200066|       40171|          0.0|       10036.5|     ...|
```

It's what was my first attempt was somewhat able to do,

```java
rddComptesParSiret.flatMap((FlatMapFunction<Tuple2<String, Iterable<Row>>, Row>)comptesSiret
```

but without providing all the good keys (department and city code were missing breaking all the sorting previously done), and also : `RDD` are no more in favor.

But that I wasn't able to achieve in *Java* through `RelationalGroupedDataset` methods that don't seem to offer such tool.

Currently, I know how to do a groupBy or a sort, that way :

```
accounting.groupBy("department", "cityCode", "accountNumber", "siret").agg(...);
```

### My question

How to browse
**each record** of
**each group**
[to perform sub calculations or other work]
**group after group**

Comment: Show input and more expected output pls, as easier for persons to follow.

Answer (score 1):

[KeyValueGroupedDataset.mapGroups](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/KeyValueGroupedDataset.html#mapGroups-org.apache.spark.api.java.function.MapGroupsFunction-org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder-) will provide you with an iterator over all rows for a given group. When implementing the interface [MapGroupsFunction](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/function/MapGroupsFunction.html) you can access this iterator over the whole group.

```java
Dataset<Row> df = spark.read().option("header", true).option("inferSchema", true).csv(...);

Dataset<Result> resultDf = df
    .groupByKey((MapFunction<Row, Key>) (Row r)
                  -> new Key(r.getInt(r.fieldIndex("codeDepartement")),
                             r.getInt(r.fieldIndex("codeCommune")),
                             r.getLong(r.fieldIndex("siret"))),
                  Encoders.bean(Key.class))
    .mapGroups(new MyMapGroupsFunction(), Encoders.bean(Result.class));
resultDf.show();
```

Being in the Java world we have to define bean classes for the datasets.

One for the grouping columns:

```java
public static class Key {
    private int codeDepartement;
    private int codeCommune;
    private long siret;
    //constructors, getters and setters
    ...
}
```

and one for the result columns:

```java
public static class Result {
    private int codeDepartement;
    private int codeCommune;
    private long siret;
    private double result1;
    private double result2;
    //constructors, getters and setters
    ...
}
```

In this example I use a result structure consisting of the three key columns and two calculated columns `result1` and `result2`. More result columns could be added here.

The actual logic happens inside of `MyMapGroupsFunction`:

```java
public static class MyMapGroupsFunction implements MapGroupsFunction<Key, Row, Result> {

    @Override
    public Result call(Key key, Iterator<Row> values) throws Exception {
        //drain the iterator into a list. The list now
        //contains all rows that belong to one single group
        List<Row> rows = new ArrayList<>();
        values.forEachRemaining(rows::add);

        //now any arbitrary logic can be used to calculate the result values 
        //based on the contents of the list
        double result1 = 0;
        double result2 = 0;
        for (Row r : rows) {
            double cumulSD3 = r.getDouble(r.fieldIndex("cumulSC3"));
            double cumulSD4 = r.getDouble(r.fieldIndex("cumulSC4"));
            result1 += cumulSD3 + cumulSD4;
            result2 += cumulSD3 * cumulSD4;
        }

        //return the result consisting of the elements of the key and the calculated values
        return new Result(key.getCodeDepartement(), key.getCodeCommune(),
                key.getSiret(), result1, result2);
    }
}
```

Printing the result we get

```
+-----------+---------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------+
|codeCommune|codeDepartement|             result1|             result2|         siret|
+-----------+---------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------+
|       1001|              1|   692508.8400000001|2.939458891576320...|21010001200019|
|       1001|              1|1.4411536300000003E7|8.198151013048245E12|21010001200017|
|       1001|              1|   692508.8400000001|2.939458891576320...|21010001200018|
+-----------+---------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------+
```

If it is possible to switch to Scala I would recommend to do so. The dataset API is much better usable with Scala.

Answer (score 1):

I add an answer here to illustrate appart the effects of your(s) solution(s) on my code.

First, I would like to thank you, @werner, and keep your answer how it is: it is the most convenient and useful for many cases, and it validates my need of asking my question, because I wouldn't have found this by myself.

So I've created the key :

```java
/**
 * Clef de l'établissement dans la ville.
 */
static class ClefEtablissement {
   /** Code département. */
   private String codeDepartement;
   
   /** Code commune. */
   private String codeCommune;
   
   /** Numéro siret. */
   private String siret;
   
   /**
    * Construire la clef de l'établissement.
    * @param codeDepartement Code département.
    * @param codeCommune Code commune.
    * @param siret Numéro siret.
    */
   ClefEtablissement(String codeDepartement, String codeCommune, String siret) {
      this.setCodeDepartement(codeDepartement);
      this.setCodeCommune(codeCommune);
      this.setSiret(siret);
   }

   /**
    * Renvoyer le code du département.
    * @return Code du département.
    */
   public String getCodeDepartement() {
      return this.codeDepartement;
   }

   /**
    * Fixer le code du département.
    * @param codeDepartement Code du département. 
    */
   public void setCodeDepartement(String codeDepartement) {
      this.codeDepartement = codeDepartement;
   }

   /**
    * Renvoyer le code de la commune.
    * @return Code de la commune.
    */
   public String getCodeCommune() {
      return this.codeCommune;
   }

   /**
    * Fixer le code de la commune.
    * @param codeCommune Code de la commune.
    */
   public void setCodeCommune(String codeCommune) {
      this.codeCommune = codeCommune;
   }

   /**
    * Renvoyer le numéro SIRET.
    * @return Siret.
    */
   public String getSiret() {
      return this.siret;
   }

   /**
    * Fixer le numéro SIRET.
    * @param siret SIRET.
    */
   public void setSiret(String siret) {
      this.siret = siret;
   }
}
```

The solution you offer uses `mapGroups(...)` with it's most common use.
Therefore it takes *n* accounts from *e* establishments and produces a `Dataset<Result>` of *e* rows. One per establishment as your `Result call(Key key, Iterator<Row> values)` returns each time a single `Result`.

But my problem is tricky : I need in return a `Dataset<Row>` that has still *n* rows : the same than the ones received at the beginning, but with ten columns added on each.

```java
/**
 * Cumuler les comptes racines sur chaque ligne.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public static class CumulComptesRacinesGroupFunction implements MapGroupsFunction<ClefEtablissement, Row, ArrayList> {
   /** Serial ID. */
   private static final long serialVersionUID = -7519513974536696466L;

   /**
    * Cumuler les comptes racines sur chaque ligne d'un groupe.
    */
   @Override
   public ArrayList call(ClefEtablissement etablissement, Iterator<Row> values) throws Exception {
      List<Row> comptes = new ArrayList<>();
      values.forEachRemaining(comptes::add);
      
      ArrayList<Row> cumulsRow = new ArrayList<>();
      Map<String, Double> cumulsSoldesDebits = new HashMap<>();
      Map<String, Double> cumulsSoldesCredits = new HashMap<>();
      
      // Pour chaque compte, cumuler son solde dans comptes racines à n chiffres (qu'il a), n-1, n-2, n-3 ... 3 chiffres. 
      comptes.forEach(compte -> {
         String numeroCompte = compte.getAs("numeroCompte");

         for(int nombreChiffres = numeroCompte.length(); nombreChiffres >= 3; nombreChiffres--) {
            String compteParent = numeroCompte.substring(0, nombreChiffres);
         
            Double soldeDebit = compte.getAs("soldeDebiteur");
            Double soldeCredit = compte.getAs("soldeCrediteur");
            
            cumulsSoldesDebits.put(compteParent, cumulsSoldesDebits.get(compteParent) != null ? cumulsSoldesDebits.get(compteParent) + soldeDebit : soldeDebit);
            cumulsSoldesDebits.put(compteParent, cumulsSoldesCredits.get(compteParent) != null ? cumulsSoldesCredits.get(compteParent) + soldeCredit : soldeCredit);
         }
      });
      
      // Créer des Row(siret, numeroCompte, cumulSoldesDebiteurs à 7 chiffres, cumulSoldeCrediteur à 7 chiffres, ..., , cumulSoldesDebiteurs à 3 chiffres, cumulSoldeCrediteur à 3 chiffres) 
      for(Row compte : comptes) {
         String numeroCompte = compte.getAs("numeroCompte");
         double sd[] = new double[6]; 
         double sc[] = new double[6]; 
         
         for(int nombreChiffres = numeroCompte.length(); nombreChiffres >= 3; nombreChiffres--) {
            String compteParent = numeroCompte.substring(0, nombreChiffres);
            Double cumulDebits = cumulsSoldesDebits.get(compteParent);
            Double cumulCredits = cumulsSoldesCredits.get(compteParent);
            
            sd[nombreChiffres - 3] = cumulDebits != null ? Precision.round(cumulDebits, 2, BigDecimal.ROUND_CEILING) : 0.0;
            sc[nombreChiffres - 3] = cumulCredits != null ? Precision.round(cumulCredits, 2, BigDecimal.ROUND_CEILING) : 0.0;
         }
         
         Row rowCumulsPourCompte = RowFactory.create(etablissement.getSiret(), numeroCompte, sd[4], sc[4], sd[3], sc[3], sd[2], sc[2], sd[1], sc[1], sd[0], sc[0]);         
         cumulsRow.add(rowCumulsPourCompte);
      }

      return cumulsRow;
   }
}
```

As you can see it involves the use of an `ArrayList`, some unions at the ends (I haven't run it yet). But you see the overall problem : it is clumsy and looks... unsafe.

```java
/**
 * Calculer Rassembler les comptes.
 * @param session Session Spark.
 * @param comptes Comptes candidats.
 * @return Liste des comptes complétés sur chaque ligne de leur comptes racines cumulés.
 */
protected Dataset<Row> calculerRacinesDesComptes(SparkSession session, Dataset<Row> comptes) {
   Dataset<ArrayList> comptesParSiret = comptes
      .groupByKey((MapFunction<Row, ClefEtablissement>) (Row r) -> 
         new ClefEtablissement(r.getAs("codeDepartement"), r.getAs("codeCommune"), r.getAs("siret")), Encoders.bean(ClefEtablissement.class))
      .mapGroups(new CumulComptesRacinesGroupFunction(), Encoders.bean(ArrayList.class));
   
   StructType schema = new StructType()
      .add("siret", StringType, false)
      .add("numeroCompte", StringType, false)
      .add("soldeDebiteur7chiffres", StringType, false)
      .add("soldeCrediteur7chiffres", StringType, false)
      .add("soldeDebiteur6chiffres", StringType, false)
      .add("soldeCrediteur6chiffres", StringType, false)
      .add("soldeDebiteur5chiffres", StringType, false)
      .add("soldeCrediteur5chiffres", StringType, false)
      .add("soldeDebiteur4chiffres", StringType, false)
      .add("soldeCrediteur4chiffres", StringType, false)
      .add("soldeDebiteur3chiffres", StringType, false)
      .add("soldeCrediteur3chiffres", StringType, false);            
         
   List<Dataset<Row>> ensembles = new ArrayList<>();
   
   comptesParSiret.foreach((ForeachFunction<ArrayList>) comptesAvecCumulsPourUnSiret -> {
      Dataset<Row> ensembleComptesSiret = session.createDataFrame(comptesAvecCumulsPourUnSiret, schema);
      ensembles.add(ensembleComptesSiret); 
   });
   
   Dataset<Row> union = null;
   
   for(Dataset<Row> ensemble : ensembles) {
      union = union != null ? union.union(ensemble) : union;
   }
   
   if (union == null) {
      // FIXME : I don't remember how to create an empty dataset with an underlying schema.
   }

   return union;
}
```

---

About your recommandation for the use of *Scala*. I don't use it for two reasons :

1. My subject is a deep analysis of cities, local autorities, balance accounts... and has many business rules to follow. It cannot be handled by a language that "only" wants to focus on Big Data thematics.
2. *Scala* can call *Java* functions, but the reverse isn't true.
   My Java set of applications include GIS, Angular and few others services. Today they can use *Spark* at the moment they wish to : it is associated with *Spring Boot*.

I hope (like *PySpark* or *SparkR* users) that Spark 3.0.0 will continue to give accurate translations for *Spark* methods defined on *Scala* API for others languages.

Comment: You can call Scala code from Java ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32107373/2129801) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1179443)) and also the other way ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15507255)). The collection API of Scala offers a lot of more ways to deal with lists and sets than the Java API does.

Comment: @werner I think about what you wrote, [and created another question about that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64016506/complete-exchange-of-datasets-of-objects-or-row-between-java-and-scala-two-wa). It could be possible at the condition *Java* and *Scala* are interoperable together, the two ways, without code duplication (especially objects declarations) or regeneration of `Dataset` one side or the other.