# Interoperability : sharing Datasets of objects or Row between Java and Scala, two ways. I put a Scala dataset operation in the middle of Java ones

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, scala-java-interop

Currently, my main application is built with *Java* *Spring-boot* and this won't change because it's convenient.
`@Autowired` service beans implements, for example :

- *Enterprise* and *establishment* datasets. The first one is also able to return a list of *Enterprise* objects that have a `Map` of their establishments.
  So the service returns : `Dataset<Enterprise>`, `Dataset<Establishment>`, `Dataset<Row>`
- Associations : `Dataset<Row>`
- Cities : `Dataset<Commune>` or `Dataset<Row>`,
- Local authorities : `Datatset<Row>`.

Many user case functions are calls of this kind :

> What are associations(year=2020) ?

And my applications forward to `datasetAssociation(2020)` that operates with enterprises and establishments datasets and with cities and local authorities ones to provide an useful result.

### Many recommended me to benefit from *Scala* abilities

For this, I'm considering an operation involving other ones between datasets :

- Some made of Row,
- Some carrying concrete objects.

I have this operation to do, in term of datasets reached/involved :
associations.**enterprises.establishments**.cities.localautorities

### Will I be able to write the bold part in *Scala* ? This means that :

1. A `Dataset<Row>` built with *Java* code is sent to a *Scala* function to be completed.
2. *Scala* creates a new dataset with `Enterprise` and `Establishment` objects.
   **a)** If the source of an object is written in *Scala* I don't have to recreate a new source for it in *Java*.
   **b)** conversely if the source of an object is written in *Java*, I don't have to recreate a new source in *Scala*.
   **c)** I can use a *Scala* object returned by this dataset on *Java* side directly.
3. *Scala* will have to call functions kept implemented in *Java* and send them the underlying dataset it is creating (for example to complete them with cities information).

***Java* calls *Scala* methods at anytime

and *Scala* calls *Java* methods at anytime too :**
an operation could follow a
`Java -> Scala -> Scala -> Java -> Scala -> Java -> Java`
path if wished, in term of native language of method called.
Because I don't know in advance what parts I will find useful to port in *Scala* or not.

Completing these three points, I will consider that *Java* and *Scala* are able interoperable the two way and benefit one from the other.

But may I achieve this goal (in `Spark 2.4.x` or more probably in `Spark 3.0.0`) ?

### Summarizing, are Java and Scala interoperable the two ways, a manner that :

- It does not make the source code too clumsy one side or the other. Or worst : duplicated.
- It don't degrade performances strongly (having to recreate a whole dataset or convert each of the object it contains, one side or the other, for example, would be prohibitive).

Comment: It isn't immediately clear what your question is outside of whether `Java -> Scala -> Scala -> Java -> Scala -> Java -> Java` is possible. Consider revising?

Comment: I want to port a part of an operation from _Java_ to _Scala_. Let's say that datasets __A__, __B__, __C__, __D__, are involved in this operation. I might wish to port only Dataset __C__, in *Scala* for example. Then __A__ dataset (created with *Java*) will join or use the result of __B__ one created with *Java* too, but also with __C__, created with *Scala* and *Scala* program that will create it will also have to call a *Java* function to get a __D__ dataset. *Java* and *Scala* language will be mixed. The overall question is : "_Is it really possible ?_"

Comment: I used this chain of interop before `Java -> Scala -> Java -> Scala` it stands to reason that the interop chain you are expecting to use would work.

Comment: Currently I don't know how to use a Dataset of concrete objects created in *Scala* directly in *Java* without passing by Parquet storage to transfer the Dataset and recreate a similar object in *Java* with a second source file, for instance. This is why I ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jasper-M wrote, scala and java code are perfectly inter-operable:

- they both compile into .class files that are executed the same way by the jvm
- The spark java and scala API works together, with couple of specifics:

  - Both use the same Dataset class, so there are no issue there
  - However SparkContext and RDD (and all RDD variants) have scala api that aren't practical in java. Mainly because scala methods takes scala type as input that are not those you use in java. But there are java wrapper for both of them (JavaSparkContext, JavaRDD). Coding in java, you probably have seen those wrapper already.

Now, as many have recommended, spark being a scala library first, and the scala language being more powerful than java (*), using scala to write spark code will be much easier. Also, you will find much more code-example in scala. It is often difficult to find java code example for complex Dataset manipulation.

So, I think the two main issues you should be taking care of are:

1. (not spark related, but necessary) have a project that compiles both language and allows two-way inter-operability. I think sbt provides it out-of-the-box, and with maven you need to use the scala plugin and (from my experience) put both java and scala files in the java folder. Otherwise one can call the other, but not the opposite (scala call java but java cannot call scala, or the other way around)
2. You should be careful of the encoder that are used each time you create a typed Dataset (i.e. `Dataset[YourClass]` and not `Dataset<Row>`). In Java, and for java model classes, you need to use `Encoders.bean(YourClass.class)` explicitely. But in scala, by default spark find the encoder implicitly, and the encoders are build for scala case classes ("Product types") and scala standard collections. So just be mindful of which encoders are used. For example, if you create a Dataset of YourJavaClass in scala, I think you will probably have to give explicitly the `Encoders.bean(YourJavaClass.class)` for it to work and not have serialization issues.

One last note: you wrote that you use java Spring-boot. So

- Be aware that Spring design goes completely against scala/functional recommended practice. Using null and mutable stuff all over. You can still use Spring, but it might be strange in scala, and the community will probably not accept it easily.
- You can call spark code from a spring context, but should not use spring (context) from spark, especially inside methods distributed by spark, such as in `rdd.map`. This will attempt to create Spring context in each worker which is very slow and can easily fail.

---

(*) About "scala being more powerful than java": I don't mean that scala is better than java (well I do think so, but it is a matter of taste :). What I mean is that the scala language provides much more expressiveness than java. Basically it does more with less code. The main differences are:

- implicits, which are heavily used by spark api
- monad + for-comprehension
- and of course the powerful type-system (read about co-variant types for example, a List[Dog] is a subclass of List[Animal] in scala, but not in java)

Comment: Thanks for your soothing response. I'm accepting it.

Comment: I worked with scala and spark during 4 years and I really liked it. And now I am back to java+spring projects. It has been somewhat painful. But I came to understand both world.

Comment: I will open an answer here, maybe, if I encounter troubles related to what I've described.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible without performance degradations or overly clumsy extra code.
Scala and Java are almost perfectly interoperable and moreover the Spark `Dataset` API is shared between Java and Scala. The `Dataset` class is exactly the same whether you are using Java or Scala. As you can see in the [javadoc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html) or [scaladoc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html) (note they only differ in layout, not in content) the Java and Scala code is perfectly interchangeable. At most the Scala code will be a bit more succinct.